# "Theme without sidebar.php is deprecated"

Tags: theme-development, sidebar

I'm building a custom wordpress theme. When I turn on debug, I get this message:

Notice: Theme without sidebar.php is deprecated since version 3.0 with no alternative available. Please include a sidebar.php template in your theme. in /var/www/wp2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2968

However, I do have sidebar.php in my theme. It's copied and unedited, from wp-includes/theme-compat

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call actually comes from `themes compat` like you can read [here in source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/80158fee6c1d55cbb5e7ce092dedf987d6befa27/wp-includes/theme-compat/sidebar.php#L10).

So I'd imagine that you simply **copy pasted** the complete contents and therefore just added the `_deprecated_file()` call as well. :D

Lesson to learn from this: Never blindly copy paste stuff without understanding what it does and why it does it.